# Unable to install Tuleap on Centos6 (glibc issue)

Tags: installation, tuleap

I try to install Tuleap on a freshly installed Centos6 by following the official installation guide.

It was failed , the dependency issue prompt:
Error: Package: tuleap-plugin-im-1.5.27-1.el6.noarch (Tuleap)
           Requires: glibc.i686

Also tried to manually install glibc.i686, but can't solve too.

Comment: Could you provide your repositories configurations (all of them please) to check why you do not have this library in there.

Comment: Which file or command should I use?

Comment: those config files are located in `/etc/yum.repo.d`. Could you show the content of the folder and of each file in this folder.

Answer (score 0):

try running this

> yum install glibc.i686

source: [Full Installation — Tuleap latest version documentation](http://tuleap-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation-guide/full-installation.html)

Comment: I did run this, but same error prompt again.

Comment: I had this problem, I'm trying to remember what I have done to solve this.

Comment: I tried to install in a virtual machine and got the same error. But today, after execute `yum update` and then `yum install --enablerepo=rpmforge-extras tuleap-all` it worked.
Probably the repository was fixed.
Note that the installation tutorial guide us to the **dev** repository `http://ci.tuleap.net/yum/tuleap/rhel/6/dev/$basearch`

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstalling tuleap: it works now !

```
yum install --enablerepo=rpmforge-extras tuleap-all
```

Comment: Your post needs to be expanded. In its current form it does not provide enough information to actually *[answer](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer)* the OPs question. You should include specific steps to implement your solution and explain why/how your answer addresses the OPs question.